# Como selecionar o nome de uma coluna no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Como pegar o nome de uma coluna no MySQL mesmo que não tenha linhas?

Comment: Por favor, não escreva em caixa alta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
show columns from nome_da_tabela
```

É forma mais simples, essa 'consulta' retorna seis campos `field` (o que interessa para você), `type`, `null`, `key`, `default` e `extra`.

Para informações detalhes utilize o [information_schema.columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html)

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'nome_da_tabela'
```

Comment: não tem como fazer isso com o select não

Comment: pq eu não queria fazer duas camadas no banco

Comment: @George vc quer pegar os nomes das colunas pelo array que o banco retorna? seria isso?

Comment: isso cara tem como

Comment: @George sem resultado não tem como pq ele retorna um array vazio. Você pode fazer uma verificação se retornou vazio executa a consulta da resposta.

Comment: cara deu certo aqui

Comment: usei show columns from nome_da_tabela e montei uma condição

Comment: quando o select for vario ele chama o show columns from nome_da_tabela